# how to insert dataframe having map column in hive table

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, complextype

I have a dataframe with multiple columns out of which one column is map(string,string) type. I'm able to print this dataframe having column as map which gives data as Map("PUN" -> "Pune"). I want to write this dataframe to hive table (stored as avro) which has same column with type map.

```
Df.withcolumn("cname", lit("Pune"))
withcolumn("city_code_name", map(lit("PUN"), col("cname"))
Df.show(false)

//table - created external hive table..stored as avro..with avro schema
```

After removing this map type column I'm able to save the dataframe to hive avro table.

Save way to hive table:

1. spark.save - saving avro file
2. spark.sql - creating partition on hive table with avro file location

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with [saveAsTable](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/R/saveAsTable.html)
Example:

```
    Df\
        .write\
        .saveAsTable(name='tableName',
                     format='com.databricks.spark.avro',
                     mode='append',
                     path='avroFileLocation')
```

Change the mode option to whatever suits you

Answer (score 0):

[see this test case as an example from spark tests](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1da7e8295cfcee15f14274b5c72ebcc997b4f85e/sql/hive/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/InsertSuite.scala)

```
  test("Insert MapType.valueContainsNull == false") {
    val schema = StructType(Seq(
      StructField("m", MapType(StringType, StringType, valueContainsNull = false))))
    val rowRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
      (1 to 100).map(i => Row(Map(s"key$i" -> s"value$i"))))
    val df = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("tableWithMapValue")
    sql("CREATE TABLE hiveTableWithMapValue(m Map <STRING, STRING>)")
    sql("INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE hiveTableWithMapValue SELECT m FROM tableWithMapValue")

    checkAnswer(
      sql("SELECT * FROM hiveTableWithMapValue"),
      rowRDD.collect().toSeq)

    sql("DROP TABLE hiveTableWithMapValue")
  }
```

also if you want save option then you can try with saveAsTable as showed [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/execution/HiveDDLSuite.scala#L1854)

```
Seq(9 -> "x").toDF("i", "j")
        .write.format("hive").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("fileFormat", "avro").saveAsTable("t")
```

yourdataframewithmapcolumn.write.partitionBy is the way to create partitions.

Comment: I want to avoid creating temp table and keep the save way same as before method above, just want update the dataframe with new map type column and save that to hive table directly which is stored as avro.

Comment: ` spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, st) .write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(path)` - using this to save avro file on given path
`sparkSession.sql(s"alter table tablename ADD partition(p1='210') location 'path'")` - for creating partition
**Note** - this is working perfect without map type column and hive table is created separately prior to this code run

Comment: `ERROR- Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: in topLevelRecord in union in map in <fieldname>`